# Pass parameter to rdlc from page with reportviewer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reportviewer, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have a visual studio 2013 web application which works with entity framework and I want to display a simple tabular data report using a RDLC report.

I have created a seperate web page and added a reportviewer control. Also I have created a RDLC file and added the data source from a C# function which returns a `List` of custom objects. This way it is configurable from the report designer, but when the page loads in the browser an error `A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSet1'` is shown.

**Report design**
[image]

**HTML markup**

```
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt"
        WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
        <LocalReport ReportPath="Alumni\Reports\Report1.rdlc"></LocalReport>
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

For above implementation I got the error of not giving a data source, but as [Yuliam Chandra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/968303/yuliam-chandra) suggested, I added the below code and now the report works.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", Business.ReportManager.GetMemberDetails(1)));
        }
    }
```

Please help me to solve this issue. I just need to display a simple report using RDLC and the data source is a public static function with an argument which returns a list of objects.

Comment: How did you add the data source to the RDLC from a C# function? Please and thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you set the data source in the page load?

```
YourReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("testDataSet", list));
```

Comment: Since I have added data source and data set in the report designer and the report also designed using the data set fields. Do I need to specify a data source again in the page load?

Comment: Show your reportviewer in the aspx and update it in your question

Comment: Hi Yuliam Chandra, I have updated the question and I got the report to work with using your given syntax. Can you explain why we need to explicitly give the same data source again in the code behind. Thanks!

Comment: @SandunPerera, based on html markup you just updated, you don't provide any datasource when specifying `LocalReport`, you can either set in the markup by adding `<DataSources><rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="TheNameOfTheDataSource" Name="testDataSet" /></DataSources>` inside `<LocalReport></LocalReport>` then also provide the target data source in the markup` like `<asp:XXXDataSource ID="TheNameOfTheDataSource"></asp:XXXDataSource>` OR set the data source in the code behind just like you did

Comment: Thanks Yuliam Chandra, I choose to proceed with code behind approach which will give me more control over loading the data to the report.

Comment: @SandunPerera, you can also specify the report name in the code behind like `ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "TheProjectName.Report1.rdlc"`, but remove the `<LocalReport>` in the aspx, this way you can switch multiple reports with single viewer..