# How to show array of string values in reportview rdlc file?

Tags: c#, expression, rdlc, reportviewer, cycle

I pass my array to reportview as a paramater and added as a parameter in ReportData but can't succeed to show members of array in a table or list.

Do I need to use some cycle in the expression?

How to do that?

Thanks.

Edit:

```
Dim myArray(2) As String
myArray(0)="0"
myArray(1)="1"
myArray(2) ="2"

    Dim params() As ReportParameter = New ReportParameter(2) {}

    params(0) = new ReportParamater("key1","blabla")
    params(1) = new ReportParamater("key2","blablabla")

    params(2) = new ReportParamater("myArray",myArray)

    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(params)
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Comment: Can you show, how you are passing parameters?

Comment: I added a short example of logic. I can pass other parameters and show in rdlc file but I don't know how to list members of array in a table or matrix in the rdlc file.

Comment: Can you write more details, like if there's exception thrown or something else. Your question is a bit confusing without details to know the problem you're trying to solve

Comment: In fact my main problem is that, I don't know how to show/list an array in rdlc file. There is no expection or try/catch block in the code. And also, I can pass string parameters and see in the report file for example in table but dont know how to  list members of array in rdlc file. Meanwhile, I can also see my dataset in table. So there is no exception or error in my code. Just I dont know to use rdlc for arrays.

Comment: Possibly you will be able to pass list by referring this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969018/pass-parameter-to-rdlc-from-page-with-reportviewer

Comment: I have also dataset and can easly list dataset in table. I don't want to use dataset for some array, I want to pass some arrays as parameters. So, I dunno how to show/list the array in rdlc file.